# Defining a dataframe by selecting a column value from a selectbox (streamlit)

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to get a new dataframe by selecting a value from the list.

```
region_name_input = st.selectbox(
'Регион',
df_ru.groupby('region_name').count().reset_index()['region_name'], key=4)

data = df_ru[df_ru['region_name' == region_name_input]]

st.write(data)
```

My error
[image]

With multi-selection, I did it like this

```
region_name_inputs = st.multiselect(
'Регион',
df_ru.groupby('region_name').count().reset_index()['region_name'].tolist(), key=1)

if len(region_name_inputs) > 0:
    subset_data = df_ru[df_ru['region_name'].isin(region_name_inputs)]
```

At the output, I want to get a dataframe in which all the values with this field are collected.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = df_ru[df_ru['region_name'].isin([region_name_input])]
```

Pointed as a one-dimensional list, eo could be used .query